# Reading file line by line (with space) in Unix Shell scripting - Issue

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I want to read a file line by line in Unix shell scripting. Line can contain leading and trailing spaces and i want to read those spaces also in the line.
I tried with "while read line" but read command is removing space characters from line :(
Example if line in file are:-

```
abcd efghijk
 abcdefg hijk
```

line should be read as:-
`1) "abcd efghijk"
 2) " abcdefg hijk"`

What I tried is this (which not worked):-

```
while read line
do
   echo $line
done < file.txt
```

I want line including space and tab characters in it.
Please suggest a way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this,

```
IFS=''
while read line
do
    echo $line
done < file.txt
```

**EDIT:**

From `man bash`

```
IFS - The Internal Field Separator that is used for word
splitting after expansion and to split lines into words
with  the  read  builtin  command. The default value is
``<space><tab><newline>''
```

Comment: Idiomatically, you would specify the empty `IFS` only for the `read` statement, to avoid strange side effects: `while IFS= read line`

Answer (score 19):

You want to read *raw* lines to avoid problems with backslashes in the input (use `-r`):

```
while read -r line; do
   printf "<%s>\n" "$line"
done < file.txt
```

This will keep whitespace within the line, but removes leading and trailing whitespace. To keep those as well, set the IFS empty, as in

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   printf "%s\n" "$line"
done < file.txt
```

This now is an equivalent of `cat < file.txt` as long as `file.txt` ends with a newline.

Note that you must double quote `"$line"` in order to keep word splitting from splitting the line into separate words--thus losing multiple whitespace sequences.